# Norm and trace of $\sqrt{15}$ over $K = \Bbb Q(\sqrt3, \sqrt5)$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have been stuck on an algebraic number theory question, could you please show me how you would approach this: work out the norm and trace of $\sqrt{15}$ over the number field $K = \Bbb Q(\sqrt3, \sqrt5)$? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What is asked is the norm and trace of $\sqrt{15}$ OVER $K$ and not over $\mathbb Q$ so $\sqrt{15}$  becomes "rational" of degree $1$. Respect to the base $\{1,\sqrt 3,\sqrt5,\sqrt {15}\}$ the number $\sqrt{15}$ is represented by
$$\sqrt{15}=0\cdot1+0\cdot\sqrt3+0\cdot\sqrt5+1\cdot\sqrt{15}$$ and its minimal polynomial is $$x-\sqrt{15}$$

Am I wrong saying the trace and the norm coincide and are equal to $\sqrt{15}$?

Comment: Neither of those statements make a lot of sense, the true phrasing would be "the norm/trace of $ \sqrt{15} $ over $K/\mathbb{Q} $", as the Galois group could change if the base field changes, as your answer shows.

Comment: It is the first time I ask myself for the norm and the trace of a "rational"; it is something like asking what is the norm and the trace of, say, $ 5 $ over $\mathbb Q$

Comment: The problem is that even if the OP said "the norm of $\sqrt{15}$ over $ \mathbb{Q} $", we still do not know which field to take the norm in. For instance, our field $ K $ could be $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}) $, in which case the norm would actually be $ 15^4 $, not $ 15^2 $.

Comment: Since OP has not clarified whether he really did mean to ask for the Norm and Trace of $a=\sqrt{15}$ over $K$, I must say that this answer has to be taken to be best. @Starfall is completely correct, however, in saying that when we speak of Norm, we must mention within which extension $E/F$ we are taking that Norm. Without a clear specification of what the containing field is, and what the subfield is, the question is ill-posed.

Comment: @Lubin: Indeed the original question does not use the phrasing ''over the number field K'. I assumed it was ok to say so but didn't realize it would cause confusion. Since the question itself does not quite clarify the extension, I would go with K/Q.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension of degree four and with $\alpha=\sqrt 3$, $\beta=\sqrt 5$, the conjugates of any polynomial expression in $\alpha,\beta$ are those obtained by substituting $\alpha$ by $-\alpha$ and/or $\beta$ by$-\beta$. Thus the four conjugates of $\sqrt{15}$ = $\alpha\cdot\beta$ are $\alpha\cdot\beta$, $(-\alpha)\cdot\beta$, $\alpha\cdot(-\beta)$ and $(-\alpha)\cdot(-\beta)$, that is twice $\sqrt{15}$ and twice $-\sqrt {15}$. The product of these four is $225$ and their sum is $0$.

Comment: I don't get that conjugate and "multiply the conjugates" trick. I'd start by writing $K$ as a 4-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space, and $x \to \sqrt{15} x$ as a linear operator on  this v.p, and your "conjugates" are representing what ? is it those https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_element_(field_theory) ?

Comment: There are many ways of thinking of Norm and Trace. One is your method of looking at the determinant and trace of your element in the regular representation. Another, Galois-theoretic way, is @HagenvonEitzen’s approach via conjugates of the element. A third is to take the characteristic polynomial (minimal polynomial to an appropriate power) and look at the constant coefficient (for Norm) and the next-highest (for Trace).

Comment: Of course, as a (now deleted) comment has said, $\sqrt{15}$ is already in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt3,\sqrt5\,)$, so if you really mean what you said, asking for the Norm and Trace of $\sqrt{15}=a$ **over** $K$, then these both are equal to $a$.

Comment: @Lubin : (at least when $L/K$ is a normal extension) the conjugates are $\displaystyle \varphi(a)$ for each $\varphi \in Aut(L / K)$, and the norm $\displaystyle N_{L/K}(a)= \prod_{\varphi \in Aut(L / K)} \varphi(a)$, how is it obvious that $N_{L/K}(a) \in K$ and that it is $= det_{L/K}(x \to a x )$ ?

Comment: The problem arises with OP’s (perhaps erroneous or unintended) insertion of the words “over $K$”. Over $K$, the only conjugate of $\sqrt{15}=a$ is $a$ itself; a basis of $K(\sqrt{15}\,)$ over $K$ is $\{1\}$, and the determinant of the one-oby-one matrix $(\sqrt{15}\,)$ is $a$.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen, I find your Galois theoretic interpretation useful and comprehensible. And you have provided the correct answer. However, say if we want to work out the norm and trace of sqrt45, with the same K as above, do we proceed similarly: sqrt45 = a*a*b and the galois group permutes the four elements, and therefore the four conjugates are a*a*b, (-a)*(-a)*b, a*a*(-b), (-a)*(-a)*(-b), which give the sum of 0 and product 45^2?

Comment: I think that there should be no discussion about the formulation of the question : as Lubin said, it must be Tr_K/Q and nothing else. Then the quickest  way to compute Tr_K/Q (sqrt 15)  seems to use the transitivity of the trace map, going first through e.g. F = Q(sqrt 3). Since sqrt 15 = sqrt 5 . sqrt 3, this first step already gives 0 . (I apologize for my typing, I don't know how to use Tex in a "comment")

Comment: As for the norm, the same process gives : from K to F, -15 ; then from F to Q, 15^2

Comment: Thanks @nguyen quang do, I see that you are working through two extensions, and it vaguely makes sense to me. I am however actually rather confused about the definition of 'trace' and 'norm' as the ANT course I am taking does not highlight this part. Could you explain what you meant by 'use the transitivity of the trace map', or give a link to a short document that explains it explicitly? And could you please expand further on the 'two processes'? Thanks!

Comment: For the norm and trace  in field extensions L/K of finite degree, consult any course in Galois theory, e.g. the relevant chapter in Lang's "Algebra". In §5 of that chapter, if L/K is separable (to simplify), the trace (resp. norm) of an x in K , relatively to L/K, is defined as the sum (resp. the product) of all the conjugates of x. Thus one gets a multiplicative norm map N_L/K : L*--> K* , resp. an additive trace map T_L/K : L--> K . The transitive property in a tower of fields M/L/K states that N_M/K = N_L/K . N_M/L, and similarly for the trace, and that's all. This gives  a "guideline" ...

Comment: ... through calculations.

Comment: ... through calculations. In ANT, you need further the notion of integers, i.e. to work in rings , not in fields only. You can consult e.g. Pierre Samuel's booklet, chap. II, §2.6, about norm and trace in this setting.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo thank you very much! I find Lang's Algebra particularly useful to me!